# Responsive image with description

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image gallery in my website. All images have description.

I want to know if there is any way to make this images responsive and when screen is in mobile size description move to the left of the image.

As you see in normal mode description,

1 List item is under the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Idea?

[image]
[image]

Comment: try text-align:center;

Comment: no i mean like block right block contain image and left block contain description

Comment: try to learn http://getbootstrap.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using @media query of CSS to detect mobile.
Add below code into style:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

  div.img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  div.img img {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
  }

  div.desc {
    width: 65%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
  }

}
```

And add meta viewport tag into head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I tried and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answering i think i could not explain my problem properly thus i edited it. as you i have an image gallery like first figure it is working good without any problem. i want to unknow is there any way to make each of the figures responsive and when the screen is in mobile size each image change like second figure

Comment: you can create image-2 to image-1 easly but image-1 to image-2 its hard to do...  first you need to learn boostrap ..thn you get idea

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xm-6 col-md-6" class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200" class="img-responsive"><!--- there if you call class img-responsive then automatic image resize according to devices-->
  </a>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xm-6 col-md-6" class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answering i think i could not explain my problem properly thus i edited it. as you i have an image gallery like first figure it is working good without any problem. i want to unknow is there any way to make each of the figures responsive and when the screen is in mobile size each image change  like second figure